# Artemis: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

I am trying to create a cluster of Artemis Servers. I have two artemis servers with following settings in the broker.xml as discussed in [this documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/1.1.0/clusters.html).

**A snippet of broker.xml is as follows**

```
<acceptors>
         <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.-->
         <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
         <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. -->
         <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
         <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

      </acceptors>
```

**I added following to the broker.xml**

```
<connectors>
   <connector name="nettyartemis">tcp://localhost:61619</connector>
</connectors>

<discovery-groups>
   <discovery-group name="my-discovery-group">
      <local-bind-address>172.16.9.3</local-bind-address>
      <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
      <group-port>9876</group-port>
      <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
   </discovery-group>
</discovery-groups>

<broadcast-groups>
   <broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
      <local-bind-address>172.16.9.3</local-bind-address>
      <local-bind-port>5432</local-bind-port>
      <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
      <group-port>9876</group-port>
      <broadcast-period>2000</broadcast-period>
      <connector-ref>nettyartemis</connector-ref>
   </broadcast-group>
</broadcast-groups>
```

In local-bind-address of discovery-groups I tried using 172.16.19.3, 172.16.19.7 and 172.16.19.8. Now, when I run one server it gives me following WARNING which (I think) means that the broadcast is not started resulting in no cluster.

```
2020-06-11 17:10:59,277 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222116: unable to start broadcast group my-broadcast-group: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Cannot bind
        at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method) [java.base:]
        at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:84) [java.base:]
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:131) [java.base:

        at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:394) [java.base:]
        at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:244) [java.base:]
        at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:301) [java.base:]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.UDPBroadcastEndpointFactory$UDPBroadcastEndpoint.openBroadcaster(UDPBroadcastEndpointFactory.java:176) [artemis-core-client-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.impl.BroadcastGroupImpl.start(BroadcastGroupImpl.java:105) [artemis-server-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.ClusterManager.start(ClusterManager.java:262) [artemis-server-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.initialisePart2(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:2983) [artemis-server-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.LiveOnlyActivation.run(LiveOnlyActivation.java:76) [artemis-server-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.internalStart(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:599) [artemis-server-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.start(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:526) [artemis-server-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.FileBroker.start(FileBroker.java:70) [artemis-cli-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.Run.execute(Run.java:84) [artemis-cli-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.internalExecute(Artemis.java:153) [artemis-cli-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:101) [artemis-cli-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:128) [artemis-cli-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [java.base:]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [java.base:]

        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [java.base:]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) [java.base:]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:134) [artemis-boot.jar:2.13.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.main(Artemis.java:50) [artemis-boot.jar:2.13.0]

2020-06-11 17:10:59,502 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started NIO Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:61616 for protocols [CORE,MQTT,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,OPENWIRE]
2020-06-11 17:10:59,514 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started NIO Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:5445 for protocols [HORNETQ,STOMP]
```

Any suggestion why this is happening? I couldn't find any online resources explaining this on internet.

Comment: How come you're using `tcp://localhost:61619` for the connector which is being broadcast? That won't work with your current configuration.

Comment: @Justin Bertram could you please explain a little bit more on it?

Comment: The connector you broadcast tells other nodes in the cluster how they can connect back to the node who sent the broadcast in the first place. Therefore the connector needs to match with one of the acceptors. You don't have any acceptors listening on port `61619`. Also, using `localhost` is invalid unless the cluster nodes are all running on the same machine (which would only make sense for something like a demo). The connector needs to use the actual IP address or hostname of the machine from which it is being sent.

Comment: Yes, I am doing that but it only finds one server. I created another question with more details. Please have a look. Thank you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345964/activemq-artemis-broadcast-sending-messages-to-only-one-server-in-the-group

Answer (score 1):

It might help someone else, I found my mistake just after posting this question

> local-bind-address. This is the local bind address that the datagram
>   socket is bound to. If you have multiple network interfaces on your
>   server, you would specify which one you wish to use for broadcasts by
>   setting this property. If this property is not specified then the
>   socket will be bound to the wildcard address, an IP address chosen by
>   the kernel. This is a UDP specific attribute.

So this is ip address of the system where artemis server is running.