# ActiveMQ Artemis broadcast sending messages to only one server in the group

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I am new to Artemis. I have two artemis server up and running but when I send broadcast messages then the messages are sent to only one server.

Following is the snippet of broker.xml of brokerOne

```
<!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.-->
         <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
         <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. -->
         <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
         <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

      </acceptors>

      <connectors>
   <connector name="nettyartemis">tcp://10.5.100.1:61616</connector>
</connectors>

<discovery-groups>
   <discovery-group name="my-discovery-group">
      <local-bind-address>10.5.100.1</local-bind-address>
      <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
      <group-port>9876</group-port>
      <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
   </discovery-group>
</discovery-groups>

<broadcast-groups>
   <broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
      <local-bind-address>10.5.100.1</local-bind-address>
      <local-bind-port>5432</local-bind-port>
      <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
      <group-port>9876</group-port>
      <broadcast-period>2000</broadcast-period>
      <connector-ref>nettyartemis</connector-ref>
   </broadcast-group>
</broadcast-groups>

<cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
            <connector-ref>nettyartemis</connector-ref>
            <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
            <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
            <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>1</max-hops>
            <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="my-discovery-group"/>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>
```

**and the snippet of broker.xml of brokerTwo**

```
 <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.-->
         <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
         <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. -->
         <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
         <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

      </acceptors>


      <connectors>
   <connector name="nettyartemistwo">tcp://10.5.100.2:61616</connector>
</connectors>

<discovery-groups>
   <discovery-group name="my-discovery-group">
      <local-bind-address>10.5.100.2</local-bind-address>
      <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
      <group-port>9876</group-port>
      <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
   </discovery-group>
</discovery-groups>

<broadcast-groups>
   <broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
      <local-bind-address>10.5.100.2</local-bind-address>
      <local-bind-port>5432</local-bind-port>
      <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
      <group-port>9876</group-port>
      <broadcast-period>2000</broadcast-period>
      <connector-ref>nettyartemistwo</connector-ref>
   </broadcast-group>
</broadcast-groups>

<cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
            <connector-ref>nettyartemistwo</connector-ref>
            <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
            <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
            <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>1</max-hops>
            <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="my-discovery-group"/>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>
```

And here is how I am creating producer/consumer and sending messages. I took this example from artemis documentation and modified it to fit my case.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new Main().runExample();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void runExample() throws Exception {
        InitialContext initialContext = null;

        Connection connectionA = null;
        Connection connectionB = null;

        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();

            properties.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
            properties.put("connectionFactory.ConnectionFactory", "udp://231.7.7.7:9876");
            properties.put("queue.queue/ExpiryQueue", "ExpiryQueue");

            initialContext = new InitialContext(properties);

            Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("queue/ExpiryQueue");

            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");

            Thread.sleep(5000);
            //brokers of both servers has same username and password
            connectionA = connectionFactory.createConnection("admin", "admin");
            connectionB = connectionFactory.createConnection("admin", "admin");

            Session sessionA = connectionA.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Session sessionB = connectionB.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

             System.out.println("Session A - " + ((ClientSessionInternal)
              ((org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQSession) sessionA)
              .getCoreSession()).getConnection().getRemoteAddress());
              System.out.println("Session B - " + ((ClientSessionInternal)
              ((org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQSession) sessionB)
              .getCoreSession()).getConnection().getRemoteAddress());

            MessageProducer producerA = sessionA.createProducer(queue);
            MessageProducer producerB = sessionB.createProducer(queue);

            final int numMessages = 10;

            for (int i = 0; i < numMessages; i++) {
                TextMessage messageA = sessionA.createTextMessage("A:This is text message " + i);
                producerA.send(messageA);
                System.out.println("Sent message: " + messageA.getText());

                TextMessage messageB = sessionB.createTextMessage("B:This is text message " + i);
                producerB.send(messageB);
                System.out.println("Sent message: " + messageB.getText());
            }

            connectionA.start();
            connectionB.start();

            consume(sessionA, queue, numMessages, "A");
            consume(sessionB, queue, numMessages, "B");

        } finally {
            // Step 10. Be sure to close our resources!

            if (connectionA != null) {
                connectionA.close();
            }
            if (connectionB != null) {
                connectionB.close();
            }

            if (initialContext != null) {
                initialContext.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void consume(Session session, Queue queue, int numMessages, String node) throws JMSException {
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);

        for (int i = 0; i < numMessages; i++) {
            TextMessage message = (TextMessage) consumer.receive(2000);
            System.out.println("Got message: " + message.getText() + " from node " + node);
        }

        System.out.println("receive other message from node " + node + ": " + consumer.receive(2000));
    }
}
```

I am executing the main class on the system with IP (10.5.100.1) and it is sending messages to only the IP (10.5.100.2). Why my program is behaving this way?

**Log Entry (IP address are changed)**

```
2020-06-12 10:59:22,295 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221027: Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge@325b0cb0 [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.f07b3018-ac69-11ea-a5d3-005056ad8516, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.f07b3018-ac69-11ea-a5d3-005056ad8516, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=03451127-a9c9-11ea-992a-005056ad92be], temp=false]@5b037424 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=(Cluster-connection-bridge::ClusterConnectionBridge@325b0cb0 [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.f07b3018-ac69-11ea-a5d3-005056ad8516, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.f07b3018-ac69-11ea-a5d3-005056ad8516, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=03451127-a9c9-11ea-992a-005056ad92be], temp=false]@5b037424 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=nettyartemistwo, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&host=10-5-100-2], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]]::ClusterConnectionImpl@2090289474[nodeUUID=03451127-a9c9-11ea-992a-005056ad92be, connector=TransportConfiguration(name=nettyartemis, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&host=10-5-100-1, address=, server=ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=03451127-a9c9-11ea-992a-005056ad92be])) [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=nettyartemistwo, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&host=10-5-100-2], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is connected
```

Comment: Are the two brokers supposed to be in a cluster? If so, please also share the `cluster-connection` configuration.

Comment: @Justin Bertram, Yes, I am trying to create a cluster to understand High Availability and Disaster Recovery. Updated question with cluster-connections. Its sending messages to both of them. Thank you. println in main class is still printing same IP for both sessions.

Comment: It's worth noting that clustering, high availability, and disaster recovery are related but independent. You can have clustering without high availability and vice versa, and you can have clustering and/or high availability with or without disaster recovery.

Comment: Are you sure the brokers are clustering properly? Can you share the logs from both brokers from the time they were started?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I just started this week on ActiveMQ Artemis. So I will explore all options. First hurdle was to atleast create a cluster and produce/consume messages. Now, the main program is sending messages to the cluster. adding the log entry and a diagram to the question..

Comment: @Justin Bertram, do you have any resources other than artemis documentation to learn more about these?